# phonegap camera issue "failed because: "

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova, eclipse-plugin, camera

I am working with PhoneGap camera and I'm facing a weird problem. I achieved to run the example from the official site, both on an Eclipse AVD and an actual HTC Wildfire, but since I installed AppLaud ADT, it stoped working and now I get the message

> "Failed because: "

with no error message.

I've tried to reinstall eclipse from scracth and copying the example again unsuccessfully.

Comment: can you post the code here or link of the corresponding URL.

Comment: the code is the same as in http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.7.0/cordova_camera_camera.md.html#Camera "Full example" section. It is a code that has already worked for me, so I think it is something eclipse related that I could have messed up.

Comment: I'm getting the error "E/copybit(104): copyBits failed (Invalid argument)"

Answer (score 0):

You probably haven't sent the image data to `onSuccess` method.

```
function onPhotoDataSuccess(imageData) {

      var smallImage = document.getElementById('smallImage');

      // Unhide image elements
      //
      smallImage.style.display = 'block';

      // Show the captured photo
      // The inline CSS rules are used to resize the image
      //
      smallImage.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
        alert('set image');
    }

navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccess, onFail, { quality: 20,
        destinationType: destinationType.DATA_URL });

function onSuccess(imageURI) {
    var image = document.getElementById('myImage');
    image.src = imageURI;

}

function onFail(message) {
    alert('Failed because: ' + message);
}
```